# Wait for multiple elements to be visible in selenium webdriver JavaScript bindings

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The selenium webdriver bindings for JavaScript allow to wait for an element to be visible by combing two wait commands like in the following example:

```
const timeout = 1000;
const locator = webdriver.By.id('test');
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(locator, timeout).then(function() {
   that.findElement(locator).then(function(element) {
      driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(element), timeout).then(function() {
         // element is visible!
      });
   });
});
```

Is there an easier way to do this and how would this be done, when we need to wait for an array of elements to be visible all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the great advantages of Promises is that you you can keep your async code linear rather than nested (callback hell from continuation passing style).

Promises give you return statements and error throwing, which you lose with continuation passing style.

In your case, you need to return the promise from your promise returning functions so you can chain your promises.

Example: Promise.all takes an array of promises and resolves once all promises resolve, if any are rejected, the array is rejected.

```
this.waitForElementsToBecomeVisible = function() {
    return Promise.all([
        driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(usernameTextField), 500),
        driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(firstNameTextField), 500),
        driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(lastNameTextField), 500),
        driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(createEmployeeButton), 500)
    ]);
}
```

Then you can chain your promise.

```
driver.get('https://website.com/login').then(function () {
    loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    return loginPage.login('company.admin', 'password')
}).then(function () {
    employeePage = new EmployeePage(driver);
    return employeePage.clickAddEmployee()
}).then(function () {
    addEmployeeForm = new AddEmployeeForm(driver);
   /**
    *
    * Wait for elements to become visible
    */
    return addEmployeeForm.waitForElementsToBecomeVisible();
}).then(function() {
    return addEmployeeForm.completeForm(employee);
}).then(function() {
    return addEmployeeForm.clickCreateEmployee();
}).then(function() {
    return employeePage.searchEmployee(employee);
});
```

You can see how the above example isn't nested and is alot easier to maintain. You return a promise and keep chaining instead of nesting. I hope this helps you and doesn't confuse you at all.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I fully agree on your suggestions to wait for multiple promises to resolve and chain promises instead of nesting them. In my example, I was specifically looking for the best solution when there are dependencies (i need to first wait for the element to be located and only if the promise returns the element check for it's visibility) and additionally doing this for multiple elements at once. Additionally I was wondering, if it is allowed to be using es2015-style promises as you do in your example in a selenium webdriver environment that uses it's own custom promises?

Comment: I haven't ran into any issues with using es2015 features yet. You can use new Promise(promise); in selenium-webdriver.

Comment: If you look at the selenium-webdriver node_module and look in the lib folder at some of the javascript files you will see es2015 syntax.

Comment: when the promises returns you can get the results by doing .then(function(elements) { //access such as elements[0] }); If you need an example I will update my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - Write a common/global function. Take single or multiple Webdriver elements as input as well as condition if you need to vary it. Loop around till end of elements and do the same Wait until each element visible.

This is how I routinely do it in my functions. in Ruby I do this

```
for each element in [array of elements], Condition
   [Below is same as your code if working well]
   Driver - Element wait until (Condition satisfied)
   element perform function
end
```

If you need to handle even multiple conditions, you can use a switch case statement. 
if you need to perform function only once keep the function outside

```
element perform function
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I really do not see how this translates to the async execution model in nodejs? The wait element would not stop the program execution but rather only return a promise. I would be most interested to see how this is properly done in a nodejs environment.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do asynchronously. Are you not testing your application ? What I am trying to say is , Its hard to think of a user using a web UI doing simultaneous things.

Comment: What I wanted to say, is that when using the JavaScript bindings there is nothing that can stop the program execution but rather everything must be done using cascading promise resolutions.

Comment: **I Assume you are testing** and not developing. If so My suggestion is to keep it simple, write a function to verify element and properties and keep looping it for a limited time until  properties are good. Repeat for the array. This will assist others in understanding/increase test readability. If you are not testing, modify your  question.